# WPF User Control Updated from Background Thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, xaml, user-interface, user-controls

I have a WPF application with a status bar at the top, and below that, a frame in which the user navigates to various application pages to perform various tasks. As the application work on this tasks, it generates transactions that pile up in a queue (local SQLite database).

A background thread, that is spun off in (I assume?) App.Application_Startup, sends these transactions, and updates this user control((how many pending, how many sent, etc. etc.)

**MY QUESTION**

I know I need to be on the UI thread before I just go willy-nilly updating control values. So, how should I request for the updates to be performed on this thread?

Comment: Check background worker https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx . It has a built in progress changed event that help you to notify the UI the progress made (upgrade status bar, and notify usefull info)

Comment: something that you can do is: 
            Application.Current.Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                   //Call to function that need access to the UI thread
            }));
        }